# Editing multiple lines at once / bulk editing with Tabulator.js

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using [tabulator.js](http://tabulator.info/examples/5.0) to display and manipulate data in form of a table. How can I edit multiple lines of data at once with tabulator? For example, if I have a table of items, with the columns name and price, and I want to change the price of multiple entries to the same value.

The goal is to mark the fields I want to edit and type or select the new value, which should be changed for all the selected entries. I didn't find anything about multiline editing / bulk editing in the editing part of the documentation. Can this be achieved in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built I way to achieve this.

You could get all the table rows using the `getRows` function, then itterate over each row calling the `update` function on the row component to update the rows data.

```js
var rows = table.getRows();

rows.forEach((row)=>{
    row.update("name":"steve"); //update the name of each row to steve;
});
```

This has a bit of a downside in that it will trigger an update of the table with each row update.

To get round this and make things a bit more efficient you could call the `blockRedraw` before the updates, then call the `restoreRedraw` function after, that way the table will only be redrawn once.

```js
var rows = table.getRows();

table.blockRedraw();

rows.forEach((row)=>{
    row.update("name":"steve"); //update the name of each row to steve;
});

table.restoreRedraw();
```